Changing the Wordpress site address makes it unavailable
I used a tool from my hosting panel to install Wordpess. It installed it under the folder my.domain/wp.
I want to change the site url to my.domain/mysite, but when I try to change the site url entry in the general settings, the site becomes unavailable.
I tried adding DEFINE entries in the wp-config.php file with the same result.
I think that the issue is the .htaccess file which has this content:
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

How do I solve this issue?

Do you mean the dashboard is also unavailable? if not, you could try to set the permalinks which would refresh the .htaccess
